# Form object is empty after closing modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two forms in two different modals. When I open the first modal, I `console.log` the form which I've attached to `$scope` (I mean n the controller I've given `$scope.updateSecurityForm = {}` in the beginning) and given `name="updateSecurityForm"` and I see all the properties like `$valid` etc. I

When I open the second modal and again `console.log` the first modal's form, the object is empty. Then I close the second modal and then open the first modal again and see in the console, I see an empty object again. I expected to see the form properties, but there was only an empty object.

The first form in modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form name="updateSecurityForm" ng-submit="updatePersonnels(upObj, updateSecurityForm)" ng-repeat="upObj in personnelProfileData" novalidate>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="vendor-name" class="control-label">Vendor Name:</label>
      <select name="vendorname" ng-model="upObj.vendor_id" class=" text-center form-control" ng-options="data.vendor_id as data.vendor_name for data in getvendetailsdata">
        {{data.vendor_name}}
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The second modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form name="addPlumberForm" ng-submit="addPersonnelsByRole(addObj,8, addPlumberForm)" novalidate>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">
          Name of the vendor:<span style="color: red;">*</span>
        </label>
        <select class="text-center form-control ng-valid ng-empty ng-dirty ng-touched" name="vendorname" ng-model="addObj.vendor_id">
          <option value="" selected="selected">- Please select a vendor name -
          </option>
          <option ng-repeat="ae in getvendetailsdata" value="{{ae.vendor_id}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope">{{ae.vendor_name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both the modals are in the same page and they are mostly similar. I used the same `name`s in the form so that it will be easy to validate.

In my controller, in the beginning I have

`$scope.updateSecurityForm = {}` and `$scope.addPlumberForm = {}` if that matters to anyone reading.

When I do the validation, I get `Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined` when I do

```
$scope.addPersonnelValidation = function(formName) {
    console.log(formName, "formName");
    if (formName.vendorname.$invalid) {
      $.bootstrapGrowl('Please select vendor name', {
        type: 'danger',
        delay: 2000,
      });
      return;
    }
```

Calling the validate function:

```
$scope.addPersonnelsByRole = function(addObj, user_role_type_id, formName) {
  if ($scope.addPersonnelValidation(formName)) {
    //valid form
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get in `console.log(formName, "formName");`?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal it's an empty object too

Comment: How you are calling addPersonnelValidation  function. Can you share the code for it

Comment: @AnilSarkar posted it

Comment: @DwightSchrute see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have put together all your code in jsfiddle and it is not giving undefined error. Though there were few corrections that would be needed for your validation to work.
I have provided the jsfiddle link at the end. Let me know if this is helpful

- required attribute is missing in your select of second modal.
- closing div missing in the second modal above form tag.

```html
<div class="modal-body">
   <form name="addPlumberForm" ng-submit="addPersonnelsByRole(addObj,8, addPlumberForm)" novalidate>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Name
            of the vendor:<span style="color: red;">*</span>
            </label>
            <select
               class="text-center form-control ng-valid ng-empty ng-dirty ng-touched"
               name="vendorname" ng-model="addObj.vendor_id" required>
               <option value="" selected="selected">- Please
                  select a vendor name -
               </option>
               <option ng-repeat="ae in getvendetailsdata"
                  value="{{ae.vendor_id}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope">{{ae.vendor_name}}</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <input type="submit">
         </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/anilsarkar/txbmg2wy/3/